# Working with Interface Builder Constraints with 3.5 vs. 4 inch screen

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, autolayout

I am having a problem with Auto Layout, specifically the spacing between two items.  Here's what the app looks like on the **4 inch screen:**

[image: 4 inch screen]

Here's what it looks like on the **3.5 inch screen:**

[image: 3.5 inch screen with error]

And here's how it should look on the **3.5 inch screen:**

[image: 3.5 inch screen with no error]

I've worked with constraints and pins without success. What am I doing wrong? Does this kind of adjustment involve code? (The Notes app logo is just an image place holder.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by embedding both labels (+ images) in a view, and vertically centering that view in its superview.